# Parse date and find information from one table to create a new data table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a table with rows representing some countries and columns representing different events which take place either in a certain day of the year or in a time frame (e.g 12.1. represents the 12th of January while 5.1.-7.1. represents the timeframe between 5th of January and 7th of January.) I have created beloow a simple example with some events from January only. But the real data contains info from the whole year (e.g. 2021).

```
   library(xts)
   library(dplyr)

   Country <- c("US",  "France", "Australia")
   Event1 = c("12.1.-13.1.", "NA", "13.1.")
   Event2 = c("3.01.-4.1.", "15.1.-18.1","NA")
   Event3 = c("NA", "NA", "NA")
   Event4 = c("NA",  "4.1.", "NA")
   Event5 = c("6.1", "5.1.-7.1.", "9.1.")
  df <- data.frame (Country, Event1, Event2, Event3, Event4, Event5)
 df
```

What I need is to create a table whith 365 rows, one for each day of the year . The columns are given by the elements of the Country variable. In this case US, France, Australia. We iterate over each row (365) and each country and check if the event took place in that day in which case a "1" will be created in the table, otherwise, "0".

For the example above the outcome should be like OUT:

```
OUT <-data.frame( days= seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length = 20, by = "days"), 
       US = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       Europe = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0)
       Australia = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
  OUT
```

The input data is given in the format above (as character). Any thought how I could solve this out?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dplyr version.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # unnest, pivot_*

alldays <- data.frame(days = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length = 20, by = "days"))

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Country) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value) & value != "NA") %>%
  mutate(
    value1 = gsub("-.*", "", value),
    value2 = gsub(".*-", "", value)
  ) %>%
  # make sure they are all the same, since not all end in '.'
  mutate(across(c(value1, value2), ~ gsub("\\.$", "", .))) %>%
  mutate(
    date1 = as.Date(paste0(value1, ".2000"), format = "%d.%m.%Y"),
    date2 = as.Date(paste0(value2, ".2000"), format = "%d.%m.%Y")
  ) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(dates = purrr::map2(date1, date2, seq.Date, by = "day")) %>%
  select(Country, dates) %>%
  unnest(dates) %>%
  mutate(count = 1L) %>%
  pivot_wider(dates, names_from = Country, values_from = count) %>%
  left_join(alldays, ., by = c("days" = "dates")) %>%
  mutate(across(-days, ~ if_else(is.na(.), 0L, .)))
#          days US France Australia
# 1  2000-01-01  0      0         0
# 2  2000-01-02  0      0         0
# 3  2000-01-03  1      0         0
# 4  2000-01-04  1      1         0
# 5  2000-01-05  0      1         0
# 6  2000-01-06  1      1         0
# 7  2000-01-07  0      1         0
# 8  2000-01-08  0      0         0
# 9  2000-01-09  0      0         1
# 10 2000-01-10  0      0         0
# 11 2000-01-11  0      0         0
# 12 2000-01-12  1      0         0
# 13 2000-01-13  1      0         1
# 14 2000-01-14  0      0         0
# 15 2000-01-15  0      1         0
# 16 2000-01-16  0      1         0
# 17 2000-01-17  0      1         0
# 18 2000-01-18  0      1         0
# 19 2000-01-19  0      0         0
# 20 2000-01-20  0      0         0
```

Answer (score 1):

An option could be:

```r
Country <- c("US",  "France", "Australia")
Event1 = c("12.1.-13.1.", "NA", "13.1.")
Event2 = c("3.01.-4.1.", "15.1.-18.1","NA")
Event3 = c("NA", "NA", "NA")
Event4 = c("NA",  "4.1.", "NA")
Event5 = c("6.1", "5.1.-7.1.", "9.1.")
df <- data.frame (Country, Event1, Event2, Event3, Event4, Event5)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Country) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value) & value != "NA") %>% 
  separate(value, c("start_date", "end_date"), sep = "-") %>% 
  mutate(
    across(ends_with("_date"), ~gsub("\\.$", "", .x)),
    across(ends_with("_date"), ~dmy(str_c(.x, ".2000")))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(interval_date = ifelse(
    is.na(end_date), 
    list(start_date), 
    list(seq.Date(start_date, end_date, "day")
    ))) %>% 
  select(Country, interval_date) %>% 
  unnest(interval_date) %>% 
  pivot_wider(interval_date, names_from = Country, values_from = Country) %>% 
  arrange(interval_date) %>% 
  complete(interval_date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length = 20, by = "days")) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), function(x) +!is.na(x)))
#> Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 4 rows [3, 5, 7,
#> 8].
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#>    interval_date    US France Australia
#>    <date>        <int>  <int>     <int>
#>  1 2000-01-01        0      0         0
#>  2 2000-01-02        0      0         0
#>  3 2000-01-03        1      0         0
#>  4 2000-01-04        1      1         0
#>  5 2000-01-05        0      1         0
#>  6 2000-01-06        1      1         0
#>  7 2000-01-07        0      1         0
#>  8 2000-01-08        0      0         0
#>  9 2000-01-09        0      0         1
#> 10 2000-01-10        0      0         0
#> 11 2000-01-11        0      0         0
#> 12 2000-01-12        1      0         0
#> 13 2000-01-13        1      0         1
#> 14 2000-01-14        0      0         0
#> 15 2000-01-15        0      1         0
#> 16 2000-01-16        0      1         0
#> 17 2000-01-17        0      1         0
#> 18 2000-01-18        0      1         0
#> 19 2000-01-19        0      0         0
#> 20 2000-01-20        0      0         0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>